# Movesense showcase app, I can't change sample rate

Tags: java, android-studio, accelerometer, movesense, imu

User experience designer, learning AndroidStudio here,

I've been trying to get IMU9 data at 52hz from the showcase app, unfortunately  I've not been successful.
I follow the documentation regarding how to subscribe to different sample rates which indicates that doing this

```
 mdsSubscriptionIMU = Mds.builder().build(this).subscribe(URI_EVENTLISTENER,   FormatHelper.formatContractToJson(MovesenseConnectedDevices.getConnectedDevice(0)   .getSerial(), SELECTED_PATH +"52"), new MdsNotificationListener() {
```

I should give me a stream of data at 52 hz, but when I monitor on the log I always get 13 updates per second like this

```
I/System.out: timestamp: 958536.0//// ACC X: 0.01914326474070549//// SELECTED_PATH  : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 958613.0//// ACC X: -0.01914326474070549//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 958690.0//// ACC X: 0.028714897111058235//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 958766.0//// ACC X: -0.009571632370352745//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 958843.0//// ACC X: 0.009571632370352745//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 958920.0//// ACC X: -0.04307234659790993//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 958997.0//// ACC X: -0.055036887526512146//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 959074.0//// ACC X: -0.014357448555529118//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 959151.0//// ACC X: -0.011964540928602219//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
I/System.out: timestamp: 959227.0//// ACC X: 0.0502510704100132//// SELECTED_PATH : Meas/IMU9/52
```

Could anyone give some advice on how to get that sample rate changed?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 4 samples per update, 13 times a second => 52 Hz sample-rate.

The samples per notification (in current sensor) is:

- 13 Hz: 1
- 26 Hz: 2
- 52 Hz: 4
- 104 Hz and higher: 8

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*